# JQuery access element using id

Tags: javascript, jquery

`jQuery("#allSelectedItems")` - When we use this jquery will check for a element with id "allSelectedItems" and will return the element if it finds a element with the id

```
jQuery("#allSelectedItems").css({width : 100%});
jQuery("#allSelectedItems").prop("checked");
```

In this case at line 1 jquery will search for the element in the page and will return the element. while executing the second line will is search for the element once again or does jQuery supports some kind of memoization technique to return the element without searching for the element ??

Comment: No, jQuery doesn't support any memoization, but you can always store the jQuery object into a variable.

Comment: https://learn.jquery.com/using-jquery-core/selecting-elements/#saving-selections. No it does not. You can always do it yourself.

Comment: Regardless of whether it caches such selections, it supports _chaining_ of method calls: `jQuery("#allSelectedItems").css({width : 100%}).prop("checked");`

Comment: store result in variable and reuse it.

Comment: yes we can store the element in a variable and use the variable to make changes. i just wanted to know if jquery caches selectors or it will search for the element again.   Thanks @TusharShahi

Comment: How should jQuery know if the DOM hasn't changed since the last call to this element?